# How to treat exterior wood that has been exposed for long periods?

Tags: painting, exterior

I have some door frames and other wooden features which were originally painted but the paint has long-since all flaked off. The wood is not rotten and seems fundamentally sound but it is extremely dry and in my experience trying to paint wood in this condition has not gone well.

What is the best way to prepare and treat this sort of exposed exterior woodwork?

Comment: You may want to peruse [woodworking.se], especially the "finishing" tag. You're likely to find an answer there.

Comment: @FreeMan I never knew we had such a specific group for that. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

A good sealing primer is all that's really needed unless you have checking. In that case, a good wood filler will do. An oil-based primer might provide a more durable base and fill any fine cracks better.

Comment: Checking? Could you expand on that I don't know the term?

Comment: "checks" are (usually small) cracks in the surface of the wood. Sometimes they go all the way through. Usually aren't a structural issue. Yet... (For trim, they won't be a structural issue because trim isn't structural.)